# order and group mysql

Tags: mysql, select, greatest-n-per-group

i am beginner in query mysql

i have table rows and value like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hf6kJ.png)

i want to select from the table : order by ID descending and group by Phone
so result will be like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtdIa.png)

pls any body help me..

i already put like this

select *  from messages where 1 group by phone order by ID desc

but its wrong

thank you

Comment: You should use group by with aggregate function, refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: @Defr - Your result image seems not matching with what you have written you want to do.

Comment: Use sqlfiddle.com  to show your result set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get latest message per phone attribute you can use a self join

```
select a.*
from messages a
join (
    select phone, max(id) id
    from messages
    group by phone
) b on a.phone = b.phone and a.id = b.id
```

Or using a left join

```
select a.*
from messages a
left join messages b on a.phone = b.phone and a.id < b.id
where b.phone is null
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below query

```
select phone, text from messages group by phone order by id DESC
```

Comment: as the text is not aggregate function so it will give you an error when you run it.

Comment: Where I have written text as aggregate function ?

Comment: I mean to say it should come it group by clause like phone

Comment: @RajatJaiswal - For what purpose ?? In question it mentioned the result should be group by phone no only. If I am reading it correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

It will not work with the group by instead of this try below query

```
SELECT text,phone
FROM @tblPhone tmp
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM @tblPhone tmp1 WHERE tmp1.PHONE = tmp.Phone)
ORDER BY Id desc
```